# Titanium/ Alloy: Reapply styles on when screen is resized

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have some basic styles like:

```
"#foo": {
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000', // red
}

"#foo[if=Alloy.Globals.isSmallHeight]": {
    backgroundColor: '#0000ff', // blue
}
```

in `alloy.js` I have the following:

```
function pxToDp(px){
  return px / (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160);
}

var screenWidth;
var screenHeight;

if (Ti.Platform.name == "android") {
    screenWidth = pxToDp(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth);
    screenHeight = pxToDp(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight);
} else {
    screenWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
    screenHidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
}

Alloy.Globals.isSmallHeight= screenHeight <= 545;
```

This basically means the background colour of `#foo` is blue if the screen height is less than or equal to `545dp`, and red otherwise.

This usually works fine. However, there are times when the height of the screen can change during run-time. For example:

- Screen Orientation Change
- Multi window (on Android)
- Adjusting the splitter position while in multi window mode (Android)

The issue with this is that the styles are not re-applied to take into account the new screen width and screen height.

For example, let's say there is a screen of size `600dp x 300dp` in the portrait position. `#foo` will correctly have a background colour of red.

However, if the orientation changes, the screen size is now: `300dp x 600dp`, but the `#foo` does not re-check the height a background colour, and thus is still red instead of blue.

A similar issue occurs when going into split screen.

Therefore my question is, how can I reapply styles when the screen dimensions changes?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `dynamic styles` section in the documentation

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styling
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles

it will give you a basic idea on how to create style at runtime and apply them. You could do this inside the orientation change event

Comment: But what about multi windows?

Comment: See your other question about the multi-windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909094/android-multi-window-support-using-titanium-appcelertor-alloy it is currently not support so I guess the events won't work either, sorry