# Android Multi window support using Titanium/ Appcelerator Alloy

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

In titanium how do I add multi window support as described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Going into multi-window mode means the height of the app can change. Therefore I need to react to this, so I can show/hide/modify elements as appropriate.

I presume that I need to add an event for when the app is resized, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

In the docs, I have only found information regarding changing orientation: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (SDK 6.0.2.GA) multi-window mode is not supported. But there are already two feature request tickets at:

- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23432
- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20553

you can follow to see when it is implemented.